# Loading Gridstack ID's from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, gridstack

I have a gridstack project I am working on that I can manually add widgets with different content. I can lay them out how I want, and then save the layout. I can load the layout back to the last save point at anytime. Here is a fiddle of it:
https://jsfiddle.net/m9rvcsu1/

My problem is that when I load the layout, the coordinates and size is correct, but the content of the widgets is wrong. All widget content gets set back to the default widget.

I believe my issue is caused by this line:
`myGrid.load(JSON.parse($('#tile-placement-string').val()), '#default-tile');`

So to fix this, I imagine I need to load the id of each widget into my json string that I use to save/load positions? How can I do this properly?

This is how my json looks:
[{"x":0,"y":0,"width":2,"height":2},{"x":2,"y":0,"width":2,"height":2},{"x":4,"y":0,"width":2,"height":2}]

This is my save function, and the click function that calls it:

```
function save() {
    return $.makeArray($(id + ' > .grid-stack-item:visible')).map(function (v) {
        var n = $(v).data('_gridstack_node');
        return n ? { x: n.x, y: n.y, width: n.width, height: n.height } : null; //add in ability to store tile id for content loading
    });
}

$('#save-grid').click(function () {
    $('#tile-placement-string').val(JSON.stringify(myGrid.save())); //save tile coordinates as json
});
```

And here is how I load the data:

```
function load(data, defaultTile) {
    gridObj.removeAll();
    $.each(data, function (k, v) { addTile(defaultTile, v.x, v.y, v.width, v.height); });
}

$('#load-grid').click(function () {
    myGrid.load(JSON.parse($('#tile-placement-string').val()), '#default-tile'); //load tile coordinates from json string
});
```

More context can be found in my fiddle.

To reproduce the problem:

Click Edit UI, then click Chart 1, then click Chart 2

Click Edit UI, then click Save

Click Edit UI, then click Load (notice all the tiles contents have been changed to the default tile)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'll add that if there is another way to do this, I am all for it. I just need to be able to load the widgets and keep the proper data inside them. I can't have them all resetting to the default widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's set `data-gs-id` attribute according to [docs](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/develop/doc#addwidgetel-x-y-width-height-autoposition-minwidth-maxwidth-minheight-maxheight-id) in the `addTile` method:

```
gridObj.addWidget(tile, x, y, w, h, null, null, null, null, null, defaultTile);
```

Then, let's read and save it in the `save` method:

```
var gsId = $(v).data('gs-id');
return n ? { x: n.x, y: n.y, width: n.width, height: n.height, id: gsId } : null;
```

Finally, let's use it for loading in `load` method:

```
$.each(data, function (k, v) { addTile(v.gsId || defaultTile, v.x, v.y, v.width, v.height); });
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. For some reason, when I hit "Load", it just clears the grid. This is the json response string I now receive after saving: `
[{"x":0,"y":4,"width":4,"height":4,"id":"#grid"},{"x":0,"y":2,"width":2,"height":2,"id":"#grid"},{"x":0,"y":0,"width":2,"height":2,"id":"#grid"}]` So it's pulling the id for the actual grid, but I need to get the id for individual widgets.

Comment: @burgoyne You probably copied something wrong. Check the updated version - you shouldn't have any issues with different names in your code.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. The load method just needs to be changed from `v.id` to `v.gsId`. Thanks again!

Comment: @burgoyne Yes, updated that part as well. Please check the answer as accepted if it solves your issue.

Comment: Just wondering, so I don't need to change this line at all: `myGrid.load(JSON.parse($('#tile-placement-string').val()), '#default-tile');` ? I thought the `#default-tile` was my issue. I guess not!

Comment: `#default-tile` is used on the very first load. Actually, in this case this parameter is not used at all, so you can remove it. `v.gsId || defaultTile` means take `v.gsId` if it is available and `defaultTile` otherwise. So when you loading from json there is `gsId` set.